# Expectation of ratio of dot product of independent multivariate gaussians

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, inner-products

I'm wondering about the following quantity $$E\left[\left(\frac{w_1^\intercal w_2}{w_1^\intercal w_1}\right)^2\right] $$
where both $w_1,w_2 \in \mathbb{R}^d \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. Empirically, the expectation seems to approach zero as the dimensionality $d$ grows (irrespective of the choice of $\sigma^2$) as $O(1/d)$ asymptotically but I wonder if there is a closed form expression (or easy upper bound) for this quantity. Or more generally, what distribution this ratio follows.

I'd be grateful for any hint. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Here is a hint to see why this would go to $0$. Notice that $$\frac{w_1^T w_2}{w_1^T w_1 }= \frac{\|w_2\|}{\|w_1\|}  \cos\theta,$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $w_1$ and $w_2$. This angle should get small as $d\rightarrow \infty$, whereas the ratio $\|w_2\|^2/\|w_1\|^2$ should be something like a Cauchy distribution since $\|w_1\| ^2\sim \|w_2\|^2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, d \sigma^2).$ Use Cauchy-Schwarz and find inequalities on the dot product between two random vectors on the unit ball (maybe Thm 2.3. here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/598/chap2only.pdf).

Comment: @snar $\|w_1\| ^2\sim \|w_2\|^2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, d \sigma^2)$ ?  That doesn't look right

Comment: It is completely wrong, thank you (early enough in the morning, the square root of the sum is the sum of square roots). One should scale out by $\sigma$ and get a $\chi^2$ distribution with $d$ degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E\left[\left(\frac{w_1^\intercal w_2}{w_1^\intercal w_1}\right)^2 \mid w_1\right ]=\frac{1}{{(w_1^\intercal w_1)^2}}  w_1^\intercal E(w_2 w_2^\intercal)w_1=
\frac{1}{{(w_1^\intercal w_1)^2}}  w_1^\intercal \sigma^2 I  w_1=\frac{\sigma^2}{w_1^\intercal w_1} $$

Now, let $Z = w_1^\intercal w_1$. Then $E(Z)=d \sigma^2$ and $Var(Z)=2d \sigma^4$.

For large $d$ we can approximate ([eg](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/38707/312)) :

$$
\begin{align}
E[1/Z] &\approx \frac{1}{E[Z]} + \frac{1}{2} Var(Z) \frac{2}{(E[Z])^3} +\cdots\\
&=\frac{1}{d \sigma^2} + \frac{2 }{d^2 \sigma^2} + \cdots
\end{align}$$

Hence

$$E\left[\left(\frac{w_1^\intercal w_2}{w_1^\intercal w_1}\right)^2 \right] =
E \left[E\left[\left(\frac{w_1^\intercal w_2}{w_1^\intercal w_1}\right)^2 \mid w_1\right ] \right ]
\approx \frac{1}{d} + \frac{2 }{d^2 } +\cdots \approx \frac{1}{d}$$

The exact value [seems to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-chi-squared_distribution)
$ \frac{1}{d-2}$