# Closed form for $\sum_{i=0}^{N-k}\frac{1}{k + i}{N-k\choose i}p^i\cdot(1-p)^{N-k-i}$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

I'm defining a compound probability distribution and this expectation $$\mathbb{E}_{I\sim Bin(N-k, p)}\left[\frac{1}{I+k}\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{N-k}\frac{1}{k + i}{N-k\choose i}p^i\cdot(1-p)^{N-k-i}$$ appears in the final distribution.

I was wondering whether there's a closed form expression for it in terms of standard functions from combinatorics/number theory/algebra etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can do is to write this summation as an integral.

Let $n=N-k$, and $q=1-p$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \Bbb E\left[1\over {I+k}\right]
  &=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac1{k+i}\binom{n}{i}p^iq^{n-i}
\\&=\sum_{i=0}^n \left(\int_0^1 t^{k+i-1}\,dt\right)\binom nip^iq^{n-i}
\\&=\int_0^1 t^{k-1}\sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni(tp)^iq^{n-i}  \,dt
\\&=\int_0^1t^{k-1}(pt+q)^n\,dt
\\&=\int_0^1t^{k-1}(pt+q)^{N-k}\,dt
\end{aligned}
$$
Furthermore, letting $E(N,k)$ denote the expectation in question, then we can use integration by parts to derive a recurrence for $E(N,k)$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(N,k)
  &=t^{k-1}\cdot \frac{(pt+q)^{N-k+1}}{p(N-k+1)}\Bigg|_0^1-\frac{k-1}{p(N-k+1)}\int_0^1t^{k-2}(pt+q)^{N-k+1}\,dt
\\&=\frac1{p(N-k+1)}-\frac{k-1}{p(N-k+1)}E(N,k-1)
\end{aligned}
$$
Together with the base case $E(N,1)=\int_0^1(pt+q)^{N-1}\,dt=\frac{1-q^N}{pN}$, this implies
$$
\begin{align}
E(N,2)&=\frac1{p(N-1)}-\frac{1-q^N}{p^2N(N-1)}\\
E(N,3)&=\frac1{p(N-2)}-\frac2{p^2(N-1)(N-2)}+\frac{2(1-q^N)}{p^3N(N-1)(N-2)}
\end{align}
$$
and so on. Using this recurrence, you can write $E(N,k)$ as a summation of only $k$ terms, instead of $N-k+1$ terms.

Comment: Thanks! The recurrence is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

A closed form solution is only feasible in terms in the [Hypergeometric function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497976/reciprocal-of-a-binomial) - which you might find less simple than the original sum itself.

For large $N$:

Letting $M=N-k$ , and $g(X) = \frac{1}{X+k}$ we want $E[g(X)]$ where $X$ is a Binomial $(M,p)$.
Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/38707/312) we have

$$ E[g(X)] = \frac{1}{pM + k} + \frac{1}{(pM+k)^3} Mp(1-p) +\cdots $$

or (hoping that the series converge quickly so that the first terms give a good approximation)

$$ E[g(X)] \approx \frac{1}{pN +qk}\left(1 + \frac{(N-k)pq }{(pN +qk)^2} \right) $$
where $q=1-p$